# "Load more" not working on prepended elements

Tags: jquery

I want to use a "load more" function like in this example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/scmccarthy22/pen/vyWNQj)

The difference is I want to use it on a prepended element with id #holder. 
At the moment I have this:

```
$('<div id="holder"><iframe src="' + source + '" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen id="myFrame"></iframe></div>').hide().prependTo("#main").show('fast');

$(function () {
$("#holder").slice(0, 6).show();
$("#loadMore").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#holder:hidden").slice(0, 6).slideDown();
    if ($("#holder:hidden").length == 0) {
        $("#load").fadeOut('slow');
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: I suspect you're trying to attach an event to an element before that element exists.  What *specifically* is failing in this code?

Comment: Well, nothing happens basically when I click on the "load more" button. When I prepended more than 6 elements it still shows all ellements instead of just 6.

Comment: Hi! I don't see an element with ID "loadMore" in the code you showed us... Is the "loadMore" button inside your iframe, by any chance?

Comment: The code in the question doesn't have a "load more" button.  Be specific about what "nothing happens" means.  Is there an error in the browser console?  When you debug this, is the `$("#loadMore")` element found when you expect it to be?

Comment: I have a button in the html code with the id "loadMore". Which, is placed under the #main div, where the prepended elements appear. Also, it gives no errors in the browsers console.